# Trying to add existing site column to the custom list using Visual Studio 2017 | (Sharepoint) [Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2017, sharepoint-online

I am building a code where I'm putting some data to be inserted in SharePoint online, but it can't recognized the "Product" item which is in the custom column area.
I want to build a code that will add the existing site column (custom column) to the "Product List" (the main list).

The only right thing to do for now is to manually add the existing custom column to my custom list.

```
        List lst = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Product List");
        ListItemCreationInformation itmCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem newItem = lst.AddItem(itmCreationInfo);
        newItem["Title"] = "This is a title! Yey!";
        newItem["Product"] = "Ultimate Gaming PC with gaming console";
        newItem.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed.  Press any key to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I expect the output to be like the "Product" has been automatically add to the column of my main list.

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet below ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following code to add site column to a list automatically:

```
        string userName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
        string password = "***********";
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Product List");
            clientContext.Load(targetList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            string siteCols = "Product";
            FieldCollection fieldCollection = clientContext.Web.AvailableFields;
            clientContext.Load(fieldCollection);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Field myField = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(fieldCollection, ft => ft.InternalName == siteCols);
            targetList.Fields.Add(myField);
            targetList.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

[image]